# Algorithm performance. I can't solve it

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve an algorithm problem, but I think my resolution is not good in performance. So if someone could help I will be very grateful.

The problem is: I have 3 arrays A,B,C. I want to know how many elements are within range of each B[i] and C[i].

```
Example:
A = [1,3,5,8]
B = [3,8]
C= [7,8]

So for B[0] and C[0] the answer is 2, because 3 and 5 are within range
and for B[1] and C[1] the answer is 1, because 8 are within range

the result has to be an array of [2,1].

Specifications:
B.length == C.length
B[i] <= C[i]
```

I tried my to solve this problem that way:

```
static int[] method(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {
    Arrays.sort(A);
    int[] result = new int[B.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        int x = B[i];
        int y = C[i];
        int init = -1;
        int end = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
            int a = A[j];
            if (a >= x && init == -1) {
                init = j;
            }
            if (a == y && end == -1) {
                end = j;
            }
            if (a > y && end == -1) {
                end = j - 1;
            }
            if (init != -1 && end != -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        result[i] = end - init + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

What do you guys think?

Comment: It is not clear what is meant by "range" of B[i] and C[i]. What is range of B[i] alone? Do we have to consider the "range" of B and C simultaneously? Does your solution work but is slow?

Comment: Will the length of B and C array always be same, because if that's not the case then it might not work

Comment: Also is ur solution slow ? Time complexity of ur algorithm is O(n^2).

Comment: I think the general idea is return an int[] where result[i] = A.countElementsBetweenRange(B[i], C[i]);

Comment: Are the arrays A, B and C already in sorted order?

Comment: B and C are predefind upper and lower bounds. They shouldnt be changed after defined.
A is sorted on line 2 in the above example.

Comment: B and C always have the same length and both cannot change order. A is not sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add something to the answer from Henry, when there are a lot of numbers, the binary search algorithm is by far the best. Also it seems that your solution doesn't take into account duplicate values in `A`.

A fully functional code :

```
static int[] method2(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {
    Arrays.sort(A);
    int[] result = new int[B.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        int posMin = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(A, B[i]);
        int posMax = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(A, C[i]);
        if (posMin < 0) { posMin = -(posMin+1);   }
        if (posMax < 0) { posMax = -(posMax+1)-1; }
        result[i] = posMax - posMin +1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

From the tests I have done with 100 intervals and 1 million sample.

method = 16368ms

method2 = 433ms

Comment: Wow, I didn't saw your answer. Maybe this is the best way. I'll try it later and then I post here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best procedure depends on the sizes of A and B.

If A is very large compared to B, it is better not to sort it. Run through all elements of A and for each one check all intervals if they contain the element. This gives a runtime of O(len A * len B)

On the other hand if there are many intervals, it is better to sort A and to use binary search to find the start and end index for each interval. This gives a runtime of O(len A * log(len A) + len B * log(len A)).

Answer (score 0):

You could just increment result[i] on the fly as you're running through the B and C arrays.

```
static int[] method(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C)
{
    Arrays.sort(A);
    int[] result = new int[B.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++)
        {
            int a = A[j];
            if (B[i] <= a && a <= C[i])
            {
                result[i]++;
            }
            else if (a >= C[i])
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with java8

```
public static int[] doTask(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {
    // Arrays.sort(A);

    List<Integer> aList = Arrays.stream(A).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

    int result[]=new int[B.length];
    for (int i=0; i < B.length; i++) {
        Integer b = B[i];
        Integer c = C[i];
        List<Integer> aList2 = aList.stream().filter(a -> a >= b && a <= c).collect(Collectors.toList());
        result[i] = aList2.size();
    }

    // System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

result = [2, 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Concatenate the array A with B[i] & C[i]. i.e
   new array will be [1,3,5,8,3,7]
2) Sort the new array.
   sorted array [1,3,3,5,7,8]
3) filter out the elements between B[i] & C[i] from the array.
   filtered array [3,3,5,7]
```

Comment: So you sort A for each interval? Not efficient at all.

Comment: if we want for each ranges concat all arrays at once and then sort the new array.

Comment: How would you make sure then that you don't count the borders of other intervals as array elements?

Comment: ohh my bad. ----